# How to move mutiple categories using Pywikibot and category.py?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, pywikibot

I know a single category can be moved by using like this:

```
python pwb.py category move -from:Apple -to:Banana
```

But, I can't find the way to move mass categories in just one command.

Is there any options like `-pairsfile` in movepages.py? It would be great if a file containing the names of the categories was available.

Comment: There is no way inside the category script (yet). The only way is to use a batch file and call "category move" multiple times. You may file a feature request at phabricator to implement such an behaviour: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/102/?projectPHIDs=pywikibot-core

Comment: I created a feature request task for it in [T291329](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T291329)